# Is it possible to generate an $M$-order Hilbert Curve without consuming $O(M^2)$ memory?

Tags: computer-science, fractals

This question is admittedly very programming related, but I felt that it is better suited to the Mathematics crowd than Stack Overflow.

---

I would like to generate Hlibert walks through the pixels in an image (or really, any 2d coordinate space), but I would like to consume as little memory as possible.  However, given how the Hilbert curve is defined, I would be required to generate the moves (`N`, `S`, `E`, or `W`) all at once, consuming much more memory that I would like.

**Is it even possible to generate a Hilbert curve in an "online" fashion, with sub-linear memory space with respect to the order of the curve?**

---

For reference, this is the definition of the Hilbert curve that I'm using, giving relative directions:

$$\begin{align}
hilbert(order) &= A_{order+1} \\
A_0 &= [\,] \\
B_0 &= [\,] \\ 
C_0 &= [\,] \\
D_0 &= [\,] \\ 
A_n &= [B_{n-1}, N, A_{n-1}, E, A_{n-1}, S, C_{n-1}] \\
B_n &= [A_{n-1}, E, B_{n-1}, N, B_{n-1}, W, D_{n-1}] \\ 
C_n &= [D_{n-1}, W, C_{n-1}, S, C_{n-1}, E, A_{n-1}] \\
D_n &= [C_{n-1}, S, D_{n-1}, W, D_{n-1}, N, B_{n-1}]
\end{align}$$

An ideal implementation would be implementable as a "iterator" (C#, etc) or "sequence" (Haskel, etc)

Comment: Do you want 'the' Hilbert curve, or do you want _a_ Hilbert curve - that is, one that iterates over all of the 'pixels' in a $2^m\times 2^m$ grid stepping from one to another?  What criteria do you have on your path?

Comment: I would like to generate "the" Hilbert curve, which I would then adapt to my specific use case.  My only criteria is that the interface is a sequence of relative moves (N, S, E, W) and that it consumes a linear or sub-linear amount of memory with respect to the order.

Comment: That makes sense.  I believe it's possible in something like $O(\log m)$ time per step (and possibly even amortized to a total of $O(m^2)$ for all $m^2$ steps), similar to e.g. finding the value of the ruler function for the first $m$ values would be, but I'd have to do some more digging to be sure.  Can you possibly describe your particular use case?  It's certainly possible that you don't need 'the' curve at all...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that I have found a solution, but I need help verifying its memory complexity.  I believe it to be O(n) with respect to the order of the curve, since the stack never grows beyond `order` elements, and each element is a constant size.

```
private static Dictionary<char, string> replacements = new Dictionary<char, string>
{
    { 'A', "BNAEASC" },
    { 'B', "AEBNBWD" },
    { 'C', "DWCSCEA" },
    { 'D', "CSDWDNB" },
};

private static IEnumerable<char> Hilbert(int order)
{
    if (order <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("order", "Must be a natural number.");
    }

    // Initialize the stack with A
    var stack = new Stack<string>(order);
    stack.Push(replacements['A']);

    while (true)
    {
        // Find the first non-empty string, clearing the stack of empty ones and terminating if none are found.
        var element = "";
        while (element == "")
        {
            if (stack.Count == 0)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            element = stack.Pop();
        }

        // Read the next command, c, from the found element and push the rest of the commands back on the stack.
        var c = element[0];
        stack.Push(element.Substring(1));

        switch (c)
        {
            // If the command is a movement, yield it.
            case 'N':
            case 'S':
            case 'E':
            case 'W':
                yield return c;
                break;

            // Otherwise, the command is a replacement.  Push the replacement onto the stack, unless the replacement should be empty.
            default:
                if (stack.Count < order)
                {
                    stack.Push(replacements[c]);
                }

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Steven, I don't think that I will actually have 3/4 of the full path on the stack, since the elements in the stack are stored unexpanded.  Only when I encounter a replacement do I push the expanded form onto the stack.

This is essentially equivalent to a recursive solution, but is easier to implement as an iterator.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: FYI, I'm treating the strings themselves as queues by taking a substring of all but the first character for each replacement.

Comment: ahh, I see - you're implicitly walking the tree, very similar to a DFS of all the positions of some game tree.  Yeah, this should work perfectly well and with a minimal space requirement - it looks good to me.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Cool, thanks for your help!